# Pair first array of 2d array with all the other columns

Tags: javascript

I have this array:

```
const data = [
    [ 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4' ],
    [ '1a', '2a', '3a', '4a'],
    [ '1b', '2b', '3b', '4b'],
    [ '1c', '2c', '3c', '34'],
];
```

What I need is to pair togheter each column with "col1".
I need to create an algorithm that create arrays containing col1 with all the other columns, once at time.

The first array should look like this:

```
[
    [
        'col1', '1a', '1b', '1c'
    ]
    ,[
        'col2', '2a', '2b', '2c'
    ]
]
```

The second array should look like this:

```
 [
    [
        'col1', '1a', '1b', '1c'
    ]
    ,[
        'col3', '3a', '3b', '3c'
    ]
]
```

And so on.
Thus, all the columns will need to get paired with the first column.

My current approach was to first create an array with the first column in a for loop.
After that have a for loop that begins at position 1, and each time pair the current column with the first one. But is looks very ineffective.
Anybody that could give some hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution.
First, write a function to transpose your array:

```
transpose = array => array[0].map((x, i) => array.map(x => x[i]))
```

Then use it to transpose `data` (I've replaced the original **data** here, so it needs to be declared by **let** keyword):

```
data = transpose(data)
```

After that, it's a piece of cake!

```
let newData = []

for (let i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
    newData.push([
        data[0], data[i+1]
    ])
}
```

And here is the full code:

```
transpose = array => array[0].map((x, i) => array.map(x => x[i]))

let data = [
    ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'],
    ['1a', '2a', '3a', '4a'],
    ['1b', '2b', '3b', '4b'],
    ['1c', '2c', '3c', '34'],
]

let newData = []

data = transpose(data)

for (let i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
    newData.push([
        data[0], data[i+1]
    ])
}

console.log(newData)
```